# Generate and download pdf file using google apps script to local PC

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a Google Apps script in a Spreadsheet that convert the Spreadsheet to pdf. This works.
How can I copy this generated pdf file automatically using the same script to PC's local folder (Desktop f.e.)

**Code.gs**

```js
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"Save PDF", functionName:"generatePdf"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Export', submenu);
}

function generatePdf() {
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pdfName = Browser.inputBox("Name of generated pdf");
  var save2folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var theBlob = sourceSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var pdfFile = save2folder.createFile(theBlob);
}
```

Thanks